# Socket.io connection keep increasing each time a new connect has been made

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, express-4

I'm using Express4 with a router that points to path `/`, and that is handled by a JS file named `chat.js`.

And my IO object is already bind to `app.io`, so inside my `chat.js` I'll call my Socket.IO by using `req.app.io`, but the problem is, I use to be using `socket.emit` and the code just work fine, but now if I want to sync up with the client I have to using `req.app.io.emit`.

And since because I'm using `req.app.io.emit`, I have the connection keep increasing problem.

---

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const path = require('path');
const randomstring = require('randomstring');
const sha256 = require('sha256');
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.io = io;
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

module.exports.users = {};

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serer is running on port ${port}`);
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(`${__dirname}/../public`));
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(`${__dirname}/../public`)));


app.use('/', require('./chat'));
```

chat.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router =  express.Router();
const users = require('./index').users;
const randomstring = require('randomstring');
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
    const uid = randomstring.generate(30);
    users[uid] = true;
    req.app.io.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log('hello');

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('bye');
        });

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Log(Image)

[image]

```
Serer is running on port 3000
hello
bye
hello
hello
bye
bye
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen instead? that console output suggests a connect, a disconnect, connect, connect, disconnect and disconnect - why is that wrong?

Comment: As you can see, the very first time I connect to my server, it log out `hello` and `bye` one time, and the second time I connect to my server it log out `hello` and `bye` twice

Comment: oh, because for every `.get('/'` you are ADDING another `req.app.io.on('connection',`

Comment: You registe socket.io event each request `/`,  callback will be append and console.log will be twice. You can debug by instead of code: `console.log('hello' + uuid);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your `/` route is hit, you create a new duplicate `io.on('connection', ...)` event handler.  So, after that route is hit 3 times, you have 3 event handlers for the `connection` event.  So, when it occurs, your code gets called 3 times.

Instead, you should do the `io.on('connection', ...)` only once outside the route.

---

FYI, you don't seem to be doing anything useful with the `uid` you are creating because you don't associate it with any particular connection.  FYI, each socket.io connection already has a unique `socket.id` which is uniquely associated with each socket.io connection so that you can get the id from the socket or can retrieve the socket given only the id.