# The process is increasingly repeated on socket.io every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a simple javascript project and when the user clicks the "load" button, it connects to the nodejs server with socket.io. because I want confirmation from the server before uploading. and If the server confirms it, it saves the upload information in the database.
The system is running successfully. However, the problem is that the upload information is repeated on the server every time.

!! I know this socket.io problem. because I've met it before and solved it using "socket.open ()" and "socket.close ()". But I don't think this solution is correct.

**server.js**

```
socket.on("istheserverready",(id)=>{

 io.to(socket.id).emit("ready","ready")
app.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.parse(req)
  form.on('fileBegin',(name,file)=>{
      file.path = __dirname+ "/upload/"+id+"/"+file.name
  })

  form.on('progress', (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) => {
    io.to(socket.id).emit("uploadProgress",bytesReceived,bytesExpected)
  });
  form.on('end', () => {
    io.to(socket.id).emit("endupload","end")
  });

 })
 });
```

**client.js**

```
function UploadFile(){
   socket.emit('istheserverready', ID);
   socket.on("ready",(rd)=>{
     if(rd=="ready"){
      var formdata = new FormData()
      formdata.append("myfiles",uploadinput.files[0])
        fetch("http://192.168.0.xxx:7000/upload",{ method:'post',body:formdata}).then(
        uploadFileSave()
        )
     }
   })
 }

 function  uploadFileSave(){
  let file = uploadinput.files[0]
  let insertfile = `INSERT INTO files (filename,folder_id,filetype) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)`;
   client.query(insertfile,[file.name,clickfileid,afile.type],(err,res)=>{
     uploadinput.value = "";
   })
 }


  socket.on("uploadProgress",(received, wait)=>{
    uploadview.innerHTML="<p> received : "+ received +"  wait : "+ wait +"</p>"
   })
 socket.on("endupload",(en)=>{
    alert("upload ok")

   })
```

**First Upload Results**

- In the "upload" folder on the server:

  - abc.png
- database :

  ```
   | id | filename | folder_id | filetype  |
   +----+----------+-----------+-----------+
   | 0  | abc.png  | 1         | image/png |
  ```

**Second Upload Results**

- In the "upload" folder on the server:

  - abc.png
  - def.png
- database :

  ```
   | id | filename | folder_id | filetype  |
   +----+----------+-----------+-----------+
   | 0  | abc.png  | 1         | image/png |
   | 1  | def.png  | 1         | image/png |
   | 2  | def.png  | 1         | image/png |
  ```

**Third Upload Results**

- In the "upload" folder on the server:

  - abc.png
  - def.png
  - xyz.png
- database :

  ```
   | id | filename | folder_id | filetype  |
   +----+----------+-----------+-----------+
   | 0  | abc.png  | 1         | image/png |
   | 1  | def.png  | 1         | image/png |
   | 2  | def.png  | 1         | image/png |
   | 3  | xyz.png  | 1         | image/png |
   | 4  | xyz.png  | 1         | image/png |
   | 5  | xyz.png  | 1         | image/png |
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're really asking about, but this `.then(uploadFileSave())` is wrong because it calls `updloadFileSave()` immediately and does not wait until the promise is resolved.  It should be `.then(uploadFileSave)`.

Comment: Is your `app.post('/upload', ...)` inside of this callback `socket.on("istheserverready",(id)=>{ ...})`.  If so, that is also wrong.  You register routes once, not over and over and over.

Comment: It looks like there's a similar issue in the client code, a `socket` `ready` handler is being added on each upload. You probably want the `ack` callback on the [`emit` instead](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack)

Comment: thank you for the answers but my problem is not with the upload because the upload working thru. My problem with the socket.io.
I think the problem is something like this, but it didn't work out for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534393/socket-io-connection-keep-increasing-each-time-a-new-connect-has-been-made